# Javascript: Audio from local file not playing without HTML "<audio>" element present

Tags: javascript, audio

Now this one really has me stumped, so I was hoping to see if anyone could spot where I am doing things incorrectly.

So essentially, I have a page with two elements. One is an HTML5 file handler, and the second is a button. When the user selects a file I respond to the onchange event that is generated, decoding the audio and constructing a buffer to be used. I know there is the HTML5 audio tag, but this is going to be a utility that needs to be able to break up the file into manageable chunks.

I have done several tests and have found that the audio that I decode myself will only play after an audio element on the page has been played. I have absolutely no idea what could be causing this behavior, since I have studied several examples online on playing audio. I will include my audio engine below.

Just to clarify, everything is handled by this code.

Thank you.

```
"use strict";

var AudioFile = function (){
  this.length = 0; // Number of samples
  this.duration = 0; // Time in seconds
  this.sampleRate = 0; // Sample rate
  this.channels = 0; // Number of channels
  this.data = []; //Audio/Waveform data
};

var audioCtx = null;

class AudioEngine {
  constructor (){
    // All of the necessary audio control variables
    if(!audioCtx){
      window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
      audioCtx = new AudioContext();
    }

    // Will hold audio data waiting to be played
    this.buffer = null;

    // This will hold the decoded audio file upon completion
    this.decodedFile = new AudioFile();

    // Automatically create buffer upon finished decoding?
    this.autoCreateBuffer = true;

    // Specify this if you want to have a function recieve
    // the decoded audio, i.e. completionCallback(decodedFile);
    this.completionCallback = null;
  }

  // This will decode an audio file
  fileCallback (event){
    console.log("file callback");
    this.buffer = null;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    reader.onload = this.loadCallback.bind(this);

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }

  // Called by fileCallback after file has been loaded
  loadCallback (file){
    console.log("load callback");
    var raw = file.target.result;
    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(raw, this.decodeCallback.bind(this));
  }

  // Called by loadCallback after file has been decoded
  decodeCallback (data){
    console.log("decode callback");
    var audioTemp = new AudioFile();

    audioTemp.length = data.length;
    audioTemp.duration = data.duration;
    audioTemp.sampleRate = data.sampleRate;
    audioTemp.channels = data.numberOfChannels;

    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < data.numberOfChannels; i++){
      arr.push(new Float32Array(data.length));
      data.copyFromChannel(arr[i], i);
    }

    audioTemp.data = arr.slice(0);
    this.decodedFile = audioTemp;

    if(this.autoCreateBuffer){
      var buffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(audioTemp.channels, audioTemp.length, audioTemp.sampleRate);

      var samples;
      for(var c = 0; c < audioTemp.channels; c++){
        samples = buffer.getChannelData(c);
        for(var i = 0; i < audioTemp.length; i++){
          samples[i] = this.decodedFile.data[c][i];
        }
      }

      this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    if(this.completionCallback){
      this.completionCallback(audioTemp);
    }
  }

  // Play data that is in buffer
  play(){
    if(this.buffer){
      var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
      var tmp = this.buffer.getChannelData(0);

      source.buffer = this.buffer;
      source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
      source.start(0);
      console.log("play");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I am really confused. I decided to give my code a quick test, and it is working as expected. Perhaps this is a bug with my browser that I am using (firefox), which is definitely worth looking into. I don't have any clue how to reproduce it though...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have figured out what seems to be the problem. This code is currently in the testing phase and it seems to have something to do with the console being open on firefox that messes with sound being played. Although, it is not entirely consistent with how it behaves, at least I know the general cause of the problem I was having.

In other words, "audio" elements have no problems whether the console is open or not, but there seems to be undefined behavior when opening/minimizing the console with JavaScript controlled audio. However, it always behaves as expected when the console is closed.